# Bash child process kills parent when doing eval exec

Tags: bash

I wrote the following code to execute a python script for multiple files. When `script.py` executes and is done with the first file in the loop, the parent process exists. I didn't find a way to trap this exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=
for arg in "$@";
do
  args="$args '$arg'"
done

for file in /home/andrew/Downloads/xmls/*
do
        echo $file
        eval exec "python script.py $file $args"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exit. The shell is *replaced* by the `python` process since you're `exec`-ing it.

Remove the `exec` to have the `python` process spawn as a child of the current shell.

There is also no need for the `eval` here, and `$args` may be replaced by `$@`:

```
python script.py "$file" "$@"
```